# Dock icons switch to generic ones

Tags: macos, high-sierra

My Dock icons are always switching to the "generic" icons, like a document with a ruler and pencils crossed. I've run the bash scripts to reset the icons and it works for most icons, however after some time they go back to the "generic" ones.

How can I make my icons constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with a reset *and* restart of your Dock.<sup>1</sup>

To reset and restart the Dock, follow these steps:

- Go to Finder
- Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down
- Now go to the Go menu
- Select the Library option to open the User's *Library* folder. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now.
- Go to the Preferences folder (i.e. within the Library folder)
- Find and move the **com.apple.dock.plist** file to the Trash
- Now open Terminal (usually located in Applications > Utilities)
- Enter this command `killall -KILL Dock`
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Once you've done that, use your MBP for long enough to know if this has resolved the issue.

<sup>1</sup> **IMPORTANT:** After doing this you will need to re-add any non-default icons (i.e. apps) that you've added to the Dock. Before proceeding you may want to take some notes (or a screenshot of your Dock) as a reminder of what you had there previously.

**[UPDATE]**

Since what you've been doing with your bash script is essentially the same thing, I would try booting into Safe Mode.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your MacBook Pro
2. Restart your MacBook Pro
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. how does your Dock look, etc)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your MacBook Pro as normal
7. Now check to see how your icons look

Once you've booted into Safe Mode, if the problem still persists, follow my steps above for resetting and restarting your Dock and see if that makes any difference.

Also, if the problem isn't there while booted into Safe Mode, but returned when booted normally, let me know. This will require further troubleshooting as it's clearly a software conflict/issue.

Comment: See, I've done this many times. And it usually resets most things (still a few icons are missing) and then a few days later most are gone again. Here's my script:


    sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
    sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist;
    killall Dock;

Comment: Hmm, some additional questions for you:(1) How long after running your script do you notice the problem returning? (2) Do you notice problems with your icons generally, or just within the Dock? (3) Does your Launchpad seem to work normally? Also, I've updated my answer in the meantime to suggest booting into Safe Mode etc.

Comment: The icons seem to disappear after launching apps... but I haven't locked down the pattern yet.

When the icons disappear, they disappear from the cmd-tab and other areas too, including Launchpad.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Have you had a chance to try booting into Safe Mode to see what happens during and afterwards?

Comment: I booted into safe mode then rebooted back to normal. Icons are *all* in the dock now... I'll see if they disappear but this may have fixed it.

Comment: Fingers crossed! :) Assuming it has, and once enough time has passed, please come back and let us know. That way other users looking for solutions will know what worked for you. :)

Comment: Yes! Fingers crossed. I'll check back in in a day or two.

Comment: Just had my first generic icon pop up since the Safe Mode boot :(

Comment: That's a bummer! :( I would take a note of what app it's for, and how long before you see another generic icon, just in case it helps narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm about three days into another reset and have had no "generic icons" appear... starting to feel hopeful

Comment: I have not had any icons go "generic" in weeks. Marking this as solved! thanks